# bash: sed search and replace the path of array elements

Tags: arrays, regex, bash, shell, sed

In bash I have an array with path names, and I would like to replace each of them with different ones using sed, like so:

```
sed 's@^(.*?)master_repo(.*?)@\1"${SOME_REPO_NAME}"\2@g' <<< ${FULL_TGT_DIRS[${i}]}
```

A sample path name which is an element of the array would be:

```
/Volumes/munki/master_repo/pkgs/apps
```

I would like to replace the path name "master_repo" with for example "somedir", which is stored in `$SOME_REPO_NAME`, so I get:

```
/Volumes/munki/somedir/pkgs/apps
```

Or with built in string substitution:

```
for i in ${FULL_TGT_DIRS[@]}
do
    FULL_TGT_DIRS[$i]=${FULL_TGT_DIRS[$i]/master_repo/$SOME_REPO_NAME}
    #sed 's@^(.*?)master_repo(.*?)@\1"${SOME_REPO_NAME}"\2@g' <<< ${FULL_TGT_DIRS[${i}]}
done
```

I always get the following error when running my script:

```
> /usr/local/bin/repomgr: line 135:
> /Volumes/munki/master_repo/pkgs/apps: syntax error: operand expected
> (error token is "/Volumes/munki/master_repo/pkgs/apps")
```

I've tried using different separaters and sed options, as well as shuffling through different quote constellations. I don't write bash scripts on a daily basis so perhaps I'm missing something?

BTW, I run this on a Mac and therefore only have bash 3.2 at my disposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use `sed` for this, `bash` has built-in string replacement in its parameter expansion.

```
var=/Volumes/munki/master_repo/pkgs/apps
$SOME_REPO_NAME=somedir
newvar=${var/master_repo/$SOME_REPO_NAME}
```

In a `for-in` loop, the variable gets set to the array elements, not the array indexes, so you shouldn't be using `FULL_TGT_DIRS[$i]` -- `$i` contains the pathname. So the loop should be:

```
for file in ${FULL_TGT_DIRS[@]}
do
    file=${file/master_repo/$SOME_REPO_NAME}
    # Do something with $file here
done
```

If you need to modify the array in place, you need a different loop for the indexes:

```
for ((i = 0; i < ${#FULL_TGT_DIRS[@]}; i++))
do
    FULL_TGT_DIRS[$i]=${FULL_TGT_DIRS[$i]/master_repo/"$SOME_REPO_NAME"}
done
```

Comment: I updated my question based on your answer. I still get the same error.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show the proper way to loop over the array.

Comment: Yes, I need to modify the values of the array in place. The last block worked out for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can even go a step further using bashes own replacement:

```
for file in "${FULL_TGT_DIRS[@]/master_repo/somedir}"
do
  ...work on file variable here...
done
```